# ActiveX controls turn into pictures in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

We've been having some issues at work where ActiveX in certain documents seem to randomly turn into buttons. It only affects one workbook at a time, and the the buttons don't work on any of our computers.

Our fix has been to manually recreate the controls each time. Recently, however, we are unable to view or run any macros in the affected workbook, and it seems like the VBA project has been corrupted each time.

This happens roughly once a month. Has anyone else experienced this?

We are running Excel 2013 on Windows 7.